# Problems with IONIC deploy for Android

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

When I try to compile app for Android the console returns this error:

> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
>   ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/albertlopezleon/Library/Android/sdk
>   (recommended setting)
>   ANDROID_HOME=/Users/albertlopezleon/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
>   Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version:
>   12.0.1 Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables. [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

But I uninstalled JDK 12 and installed JDK 8 and also defined the env variables, I can't understand what's happening.

The project info is that:

Ionic:

> ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)    Ionic Framework               :
>   @ionic/angular 4.2.0    @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.8
>   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4    @angular/cli
>   : 7.3.8    @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1

Cordova:

> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)    Cordova
>   Platforms     : android 8.0.0, ios 5.0.0    Cordova Plugins       :
>   cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
>   3.1.2, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

> Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
>   (/Users/albertlopezleon/Library/Android/sdk)    ios-deploy        :
>   1.9.4    ios-sim           : 7.0.0    NodeJS            : v11.1.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)    npm               : 6.9.0    OS
>   : macOS High Sierra    Xcode             : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version
>   9F2000

Answer (score 0):

1. Just remove `..bla..bla/<JAVA 12 location>/bin` from environmental
   variable named **PATH** or **uninstall java 12** from your PC if you don't want.
2. Then try the same command with a new CMD prompt.

I hope it would help anyone.
Thank you :)

Comment: Works!. Thanks for the help :).